# How to avoid headers already sent and change cookie related settings

Tags: php, session, header

Im trying to make a function to securely start a new session for my script and also modify cookie settings.

This is the function:

```
public function sessionStart($sessID, $noCache)
    {
        session_start();

        if($noCache)
        {
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
        }

        // **PREVENTING SESSION HIJACKING**
        // Prevents javascript XSS attacks aimed to steal the session ID
        ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);

        // **PREVENTING SESSION FIXATION**
        // Session ID cannot be passed through URLs
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        // Uses a secure connection (HTTPS) if possible
        ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);

        session_name($sessID);

        // Finally start a new session.
    }
```

I've tryied everything 'google' shown me but still i have this error about the headers:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Its there a way to make my function work?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually caused by you having duplicated `session_start()`'s in your code.

Make sure that you're only starting the session once per script. One way to do this is to put an echo/logging system in place so that you can see how many times the function is hit.

See here: [PHPaste Snippet](https://phpaste.ga/paste/f7560c).

Also, it might be a good idea to have `ini_set([...])` stuff before `session_start()`, so you're making sure it behaves as expected when run.